# Variable incrementing twice instead of once

Tags: javascript

At the end of my program, I increment 'level' in evalSeqResults() and then display the results (though i'm adding different requirements in this method later on)

When the resultStr appears on screen, it has the correct level, but then after a few seconds, 'level' increases one more time and so do the other 2 variables relying on it

Does anyone know why this is?

Here's some more code: http://pastebin.com/RuKLadmK

```
function endSequence() {     
    evalSeqResults(); 
    displaySeqResults();
 }

function evalSeqResults() {
    level++;
}

function displaySeqResults() {
    var resultStr = "You scored " + correctCount + " out of " + (NUM_OF_STACKS + 20) +
    "<br/>";
    resultStr += "Your next level is: " + level + "<br/>";
    resultStr += "There will be " + LEVELS[level].numDecks + " decks and you are looking for " + LEVELS[level].nBack + " back. <br/>";
    resultStr += "Press START to continue";
    $('#resultspara').html(resultStr);
    $('#resultspara').show(0);
 }
```

Comment: Are you calling `endSequence` twice? Not really much we can say here. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which shows the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: there is obviously some code that we don't see here that is causing the problem

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) can help us to help you to solve this issue faster.

Comment: I added a pastebin doc..does that help any?

Comment: No. What do `restart();` and `resetAllStacks();` do?

Comment: Those two methods just hide a bunch of stuff. I added them to the doc if you wanted to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `level` variable is defined nowhere. However, I found a glitch in your code, at the point where `endSequence` is called:

```
function doNext() {
     if (cardNum < maxCard) {
          cardNum++;
          fixate();
     }
     if (cardNum == maxCard) {
          endSequence();
     }
}
```

Let's say, `cardNum` is `4` and `maxCard` is `5`. The first time `doNext` is called, the first condition is true. `cardNum` is increased to `5` and `fixate` is called. After that, the second condition is also true (`5==5`) - `endSequence` is called. The second time `doNext` is called, only the second condition matches and is `endSequence` is executed again.

I guess you wanted:

```
function doNext() {
     if (cardNum < maxCard) {
          cardNum++;
          fixate();
     } else if (cardNum == maxCard) {
//     ^^^^
          endSequence();
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. That else if was it.  (I do define level higher up in my code.)

Comment: You are just training my bug hunting skills :-)